Intuition for Exponential Sheaf Sequence via Winding Number
I have a question about the geometric intuition behind exponential sheaf sequence
$$ 0\to 2\pi i\,\mathbb Z \to \mathcal O_M\to\mathcal O_M^*\to 0 $$
inducing long cohomological sequence. In wikipedia is stated that that the right map in
$$\cdots\to H^0(\mathcal O_U) \to H^0(\mathcal O_U^*)\to H^1(2\pi i\,\mathbb Z|_U) \to...$$
allows intuitive interpretation as associating to  each section $s$ of $H^0(\mathcal O_U^*)$ via the connecting homomorphism to $H^1(2\pi i\,\mathbb Z|_U)$ the map associating the winding number for each loop.
How to interpret this? Assume $U := B_1(0) -\{0 \}$ is the pointed unit disc. Then a section $s \in H^0(\mathcal O_U^*)$ can be regarded as an analytic map $s: U \to \mathbb{C}^*$. How does it's image under the connecting homomorphism to $H^1(2\pi i\,\mathbb Z|_U)$ look like following this explanations above.
Does it just mean that this image of $s$ in $H^1(2\pi i\,\mathbb Z|_U)$ is regarded as a function associating to any loop $L \cong S^1 \subset U$ the winding number for the image $s(L)$, regarded as $s$ restricted to this loop $L \subset U$, in other words the composition of $s$ and inclusion $L \cong S^1 \subset U$ which can be regarded as a loop function $s(L): S^1 \to \mathbb{C}^*$?
Or is there something differently going on?

Did you try to work out the example $U=\mathbb C^*$ and $s=\frac 1 z$?

@red_trumpet: if I'm not missing something then the connection morphism in the quoted excerpt would there be given as the map $s$ \to the map $\int_{-}s \cdot dz: \gamma \mapsto \int_{\gamma}s \cdot dz $ (ie in case of $s=1/z$ the residue (for your $s$ it's $1/2 \pi i$) times loop count times $(2 \pi i)$-factor. Are these considerations correct?

@red_trumpet: also this seemingly also indicates the historical reason why the constant sheaf $2\pi i,\mathbb Z$ in the exponent sequence condemned to carry this - at first glance mysterious - $2 \pi i$ factor with it for all time in the world - which also appears (...seemingly also mainly from historical reasons; indeed formally I not see any reason why one couldn't replace by any $c \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$) as prefactor of Tate Hodge structure. Do you maybe see a connection?

Your computation looks almost fine to me, I guess you should divide by $2 \pi i$ to obtain the winding number. Regarding the factor $2\pi i$ in the sequence: That is there because for a complex number $z$ you have $\exp(z) = 1 \iff z \in 2\pi i \mathbb Z$. So the kernel of $\exp$ is $2\pi i \mathbb Z$. Personally I prefer to put it into the map $\mathcal O \to \mathcal O^$, so this becomes $f \mapsto \exp(2\pi i f)$. Then the sequence looks like $$0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathcal O_M \to \mathcal O_M^ \to 0.$$
